# show/hide checkbox when values in the dropdown selected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$(function cbclicked() {
    $('#CBAllPlates').hide();
    $('#ddlPlate').change(function () {
        if ($('#ddlPlate').val() == "Broth") {
            $('#CBAllPlates').show();
        } else {
            $('#CBAllPlates').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Anyone knows why this won't work? All I want is every time any value in the drop down list "ddlPlate" is clicked to hide my checkbox "CBAllPlates". I also have the drop down list & checkbox in variables .Client idk if that is a problem

Comment: post your html too please

Comment: Did you hook the click event to the function `cbclicked`?

Comment: "How do you add html to this? Im new to stackoverflow'

Comment: @AaronMoore well first of all stop putting quote marks in your comments, it looks weird... you can click **edit** under the tags on your question and simply stick in your html and click save

Answer (score 2):

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz63kvzm/)  here is the code which runs on `load` of page :

```
<select id="ddlPlate">
    <option value="">Select</opion>
    <option value="Broth">Broth</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="CBAllPlates"/>


$(function() {
$('#CBAllPlates').hide();
$('#ddlPlate').change(function () {
    if ($('#ddlPlate').val() == "Broth") {
        $('#CBAllPlates').show();
    } else {
        $('#CBAllPlates').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is right but wrong placed code and check the link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pn9br187/)

```
$(function(){

    $(".bookMovieCheck").hide();
    $("#movies").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "bahubali"){
            $(".bookMovieCheck").show();
        }else{
            $(".bookMovieCheck").hide();
        }
    });

});
```